# Location of the values ​in the Highcharts.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, styles

I'm trying to make bar chart looks like in picture [here](https://clip2net.com/s/3YJIKRy): 
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/VasyaCV/gmqrsfc7/6/) is the result that I got
Maybe someone can suggest, how can I sticked value to xAxis?
Series I want to plot are :

```
series: [{
           name: 'text',
           data: [{"color":"#17a78b","y":3.36},
             {"color":"#17a78b","y":2.1},{"color":"#17a78b","y":1.67}, 
             {"color":"#17a78b","y":2.07},{"color":"#17a78b","y":-3.89},
             {"color":"#17a78b","y":2.73},{"color":"#17a78b","y":2.34},
             {"color":"#17a78b","y":2.91},{"color":"#56e8cb","y":4.94},
             {"color":"#56e8cb","y":2.99},{"color":"#56e8cb","y":-2.5},
             {"color":"#56e8cb","y":3.77}]
                                }]
```

Or maybe there is some way to style negative and positive value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it using `Highcharts.SVGElement.translate` method. Each data label is SVG element which you can translate depend on your needs. This solution is more flexible because you can add more custom logic by analyzing point and label heights. Check demo and code I posted you below.

**Code:**

```
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
        render: function() {
        var chart = this,
            series = chart.series[0],
            offset = 3,
            pointHeight,
            textHeight,
            translateY;

        series.points.forEach(function(point) {
            textHeight = point.dataLabel.getBBox().height;
          pointHeight = point.shapeArgs.height;

          if (pointHeight < textHeight) {
            translateY = (pointHeight - textHeight / 2) + textHeight + offset;
          } else {
            translateY = (pointHeight - textHeight / 2) - offset;
          }

          translateY = (point.y < 0) ? -translateY : translateY;
          point.dataLabel.translate(0, translateY);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/30bxv9rc/

**Api reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#translate 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Thank you, it's really helped me

Answer (score 0):

First set `plotOptions.column.stacking` to `normal` so that data labels are displayed inside the columns.

Next, you will need to update each point of data in the `series` through another function after the chart is rendered. Referring to my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8hwbos6d/), data points are looped; its value is accessed to check positive or negative; and subsequently `verticalAlign` and `y` attributes are updated so that label is displayed according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion